# Can't see Azure B2C Directory

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I recently transferred the billing ownership for an azure subscription from one azure account to another.
Now, although the B2C tenants show in the Azure portal for the new account, I cannot see the B2C directory to switch to in order to manage users. When I login to the old Azure account, I can see the directory and can still manage the users.
How can I ensure that the directory is owned and managed by the new account where the tenant is now owned?

Comment: Have you added the new account to the tenant and grant it a role(say global admin)?

Comment: @ray struggling to work out how to do that

Comment: You would need to sign in to Azure with the account you used before, switch to the B2C directory, and then invite the new account(s) there and grant them roles.

Comment: thank you so much ray and @junnas - that worked perfectly. If someone creates an answer based on this I'll accept

Comment: @DavidWard Glad that your problem is solved; but sorry to say that, from my honest opinion, this seems a cloud config problem rather than a programming question. I would say it might be better to close it.

Answer (score 0):

> I agree with *@ray* and *@juunas*, you need to **invite** your new account in B2C tenant and grant roles accordingly.

I have one user named **Sri** who can view B2C tenant details in Portal:

[image]

But cannot switch to that B2C directory as it's not showing in `All Directories` like this:

[image]

To make this account access B2C tenant, sign into that tenant with old account and **invite** user by adding email as below:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Switch to B2C tenant -> Azure AD B2C -> Users -> New user -> Invite user*

[image]

You can grant **directory role** to that user while inviting itself like this:

[image]

Clicking **`Invite`** button will send mail to that user with **Accept Invitation** link as below:

[image]

While accepting the invitation, it will ask the user to accept the **consent prompt** like this:

[image]

When I checked `All Directories` tab of *Sri* user after accepting the above consent, it showed B2C directory too with **Switch** option successfully:

[image]